# SQL union for one identical column

Tags: sql-server, union

I have a SQL table for the translation of my website like this :

TRANSLATE

- id : xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx
- Label : lbl_name
- Translate : name
- Language : English

I'm trying to give for users a custom translation, where the users can set one or more labels 
So he will have something like :

- id : xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx
- Label: lbl_name
- Translate : n4m3
- Language : EnglishCustom

I want to Select all from TRANSLATE where Languague = "English"

Then Select all from TRANSLATE where Languague = "EnglishCustom"

And do a Union only for the Name's column. So if we have an identical Name (here: lbl_name), i give the priority on the EnglishCustom to get "N4M3", not "name".

I just want to understand how we can doing a : If we have 2 identical Label, so the user added a trad on this label, so GET the Translate on the EnglishCustom and not on the English, With a SQL request

Can you help me please ? thank you

Comment: If you want to get an answer that suits your exact needs you better provide the information needed. All the answers below solve your described problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got your query ready and just need to return the right values you might want to have a look into [coalesce()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

Lets assume this query (just to eyplain, might not work):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.TRANSLATE,t1.TRANSLATE)
FROM TRANSLATE t1
  LEFT JOIN TRANSLATE t2
         ON t1.label = t2.label
        AND t2.Languague = CONCAT (t1.Languague,'Custom')
WHERE t1.Languague = 'English'
```

COALESCE will return the first non null value.
If the LEFT JOIN does not join to any custom name the default will be returned.

In this [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vUUNgyvA) i did a quick test with a MySQL table that should also work for you.

Comment: Thanks you for your time! 
I need to get a complete object (to do serialization), but this query return only one column. Your query is perfect with a Language = English and EnglishCustom.  I explained my problem like this but in my real code, i have a LanguageId, because i have an other table for the Language, do this still work with this difference ?

Comment: You can easily add the desired columns to the output. Regarding LanguageID you can simply join t1 to your language table

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
select id,Label,Translate,Languague
from
(select id,Label,Translate,Languague,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id,label order by languague desc) rn
from TRANSLATE
where Languague in('English','EnglishCustom')) a
where a.rn =1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  Label       Translate   Languague
1   lbl_name    n4m3        EnglishCustom
```

Comment: this work very good, but the old value "name" is still return, there is now "n4m3" and "name" , can we remove the "name" ?

Comment: My query is returning only 'N4M3' not name for that only i used the condition where a.rn =1.

Comment: i tryied many times but never working for me... but finaly i got the answer, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(
SELECT * , 1 as Seq 
FROM TRANSLATE where Languague = "EnglishCustom"
UNION ALL 
SELECT * ,2 as Seq 
FROM TRANSLATE where Languague = "English"
) AS myTab
ORDER BY Seq
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. ! this work perfectly on one column. but i have to get 1700 translate (english) + (ex:) 10 translate (englishCustom), and bind the data to have finally only 1700 translate, where the indenticals data on the english are binded with the englishCustom, i try to have this result !

Comment: the first query might be where Languague <> "English"